# run spark machine learning example on yarn failed

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

After start the dfs, yarn and spark, I run these code under the root directory of spark on master host:

`MASTER=yarn ./bin/run-example ml.LogisticRegressionExample \ data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt`

Actually I get these code from Spark's README, and here is the source code about LogisticRegressionExample on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/LogisticRegressionExample.scala

Then error occurs:

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/root/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt;`

Firstly, I don't know why it's `hdfs://master:9000/user/root`, I do set namenode's IP address to `hdfs://master:9000`, but why spark chose `/user/root`?

Then, I make a directory `/user/root/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt` on every host of the cluster, so I hope spark can find this file. But the same error occurs again. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is looking for the file on HDFS, not the regular Linux file system.  The path you've given to your data (data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt) is a relative path.  In HDFS, relative paths are assumed to begin within your home directory.

The LogRegExample.scala on github assumes a local execution, not a yarn execution.  If you want to perform a yarn execution then you need to upload files to HDFS.

Comment: @JamCon.Yes, it works. I can use `hdfs dfs -put` to put the data file onto HDFS first than `run-example`. when I use `spark-submit` to submit python script, I use `--files` to upload my data file, but how can I specify the path of the uploaded file on HDFS? And will the total runtime of my submitted script include the time for uploading?